# AWS Pointing Elastic Beanstalk to a specific RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have 3 environments, all set up in the same region through Elastic Beanstalk - dev, test, prod.

The end goal that I would like is to make a copy of the production database and have the test EB environment point at the copy of the production database.

I've been going through AWS docs but not having any luck finding any good material (shocker right?). I've found how to take snapshots of the database, but within EB I'm not seeing any options of how to change the database that it is using.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The configuration would not be within EBS.  I actually don't know what EBS has to do with your question.  You would simply instantiate a new RDS instance from one of the RDS snapshots you have created.

You would need to have some configuration within your application to understand what environment your code is currently running in (i.e. dev, test, prod) and which RDS endpoint should be used for that environment.

Comment: Edited question to remove EBS references; OP almost certainly was referring to Elastic Beanstalk as "EBS," which as you point out, refers to something else entirely, and doesn't make sense here.